# Push a Docker Compose to a Production Server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm running a docker compose stack with multiple containers locally on my development computer.

How am I supposed to get the whole compose to the production server ?

I've got a server set up in Digital Ocean, Ubuntu 16.04 with docker installed.

How do I get my whole project from my desktop to the server?

Comment: DO has a tutoral for the setup to use docker-machine for that https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-provision-and-manage-remote-docker-hosts-with-docker-machine-on-ubuntu-16-04. After you connected to the remote docker daemon you can simply use the same command you would use to run it locally.

Comment: I'll check it out later this evening. Thanks!

Comment: May be I'm misinterpreting, why don't you use the same compose file and run it on production server as you did it in local?

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I do

```
docker-machine create --driver digitalocean --swarm-experimental --digitalocean-access-token YOUR_TOKEN MACHINE_NAME

eval $(docker-machine env MACHINE_NAME)

docker-compose build

docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Hey ! I fixed it back then by hooking our master branch on github to our docker hub images. When a new release was pushed to the master, docker hub would recreate the image and a webhook to our production server would be triggered ( to update the image ) after the creation of the image was done. Worked good. Thanks anyways :)